# Converging or Diverging Series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

What test do i use to show this series converges or diverges?

$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{r})^{r}}$$

I know that $(1+\frac{1}{r})^{r} \rightarrow e$ so does this function converge to $\frac{1}{e}$? and is it sufficient just to say that?

Comment: Why is there an equal to sign in between sigma and the function ???

Answer (score 1):

Yes, looking at the limit you gave is sufficient: the series diverges. It is [a basic (yet fundamental) result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test) that if the series $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then it must be the case that $a_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have determined that the **sequence** $$a_r=\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{r})^r}$$ converges to $\frac{1}{e}$.

This is a sufficient condition to conclude that the **series**
$$\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{a_r}=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{r})^r}}$$
**diverges**.

In order for a series to converge, it is necessary that the terms within the series converge to $0$.  This should make sense if you consider that, in the above case, as r approaches infinity, $\frac{1}{e}$ must be continually added to the total (and it will therefore keep growing).  In order for the series to converge, eventually, you must be adding $0$'s to the total.